# SAPUI5 Routing - Difference between controlId and targetControl

Tags: javascript, routes, sapui5

In my routing configuration I can either set the property "*controlId*" or "*targetControl*" to specify the ID of the control where I want to put my new view. The only difference I figured out so far is that it seems that "*controlId*" has a higher priority. Means: If I specify both *controlId* is used.

Despite that, is there any difference between these keys or are they synonyms?
The same goes for "*targetAggregation*" and "*controlAggregation*"?

I've read a lot of SAP documentation but I couldn't find a page where every parameter is explained and especially I wasn't able to find the answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.Route.html#constructor) states *targetControl* and *targetAggregation* as deprecated since 1.28.

In the [sourcecode](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.38/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/routing/Route.js#L305) you can find some places where the pre 1.28 route configs are converted to the new route config including targets, which were introduced at that version. That might explain the naming: ***target***Control and ***target***Aggregation have there origin a time where there was no separate target configuration object but everything was defined within the route.

You can find the available parameters more or less explained in the developer guide: [overview](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/3d18f20bd2294228acb6910d8e8a5fb5.html) and more details on parameters [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/902313063d6f45aeaa3388cc4c13c34e.html).