# Navigating from detail view to another view

Tags: sapui5

I am working on a sapui5 fiori master detail app, and I can't seem to move from one view to another even though I read the documentation and applied it in there.

I have created an "example" view and I want to move from detail to example and then return to detail, but can't seem to work.
Here's my detail controller's move button:

```
move : function () {
   var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
   oRouter.navTo("example", {
                     });
    },
```

and here's example controller's return button :

```
return : function () {
        var oHistory = History.getInstance();
        var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();

        if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
            // The history contains a previous entry
            history.go(-1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise we go backwards with a forward history
            var bReplace = true;
            this.getRouter().navTo("detail", {
                entity: "equipementSet('10000004')"
            } , bReplace);
        }
},
```

and finally my manifest.json code :

```
    "routes": [
            {
                "pattern": "",
                "name": "main",
                "view": "Master",
                "targetAggregation": "masterPages"
            },
            {
                "pattern": "{entity}/:tab:",
                "name": "detail",
                "view": "Detail",
                "targetAggregation": "detailPages",
                "targetControl": "idAppControl"

            },
            {
                "pattern": "example",
                "name": "example",
                "view": "example",
                "targetAggregation": "detailPages",
                "targetControl": "idAppControl"

            }...
```

Comment: Try this  oRouter.navTo("example");

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: If you switch to debug mode, do you see any errors in console or network tab ? I assume, you are familiar with the tutorial about [navigation and routing](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d.html)? There are several sample applications in WebIDE. Their coding might also help. Could you please post your complete manifest.json?

Comment: Which UI5 release do you use ?
Please see also [this posting on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489463/sapui5-routing-difference-between-controlid-and-targetcontrol)

Comment: Did you also add a target in you manifest.json? The route targets a target which has to be defined in the manifest.json